# Why can't I create a map with folium markers?

Tags: python, pandas, folium

i have a problem with plot map in folium.
I have three columns:
Latitude    Longitude   City
0   18.456792   -69.951164  Santo Domingo
1   19.371887   -99.086624  Mexico city
2   15.478598   120.599741  Unknown
3   37.997490   23.762728   Athens
4   33.580412   130.396361  Fukouka

and i want to add marker.
My code is :

```
m = folium.Map(location=[20,0], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=2)
m

for i in range(0,len(terroryzm)):
   folium.Marker(
      location=[terroryzm['Latitude'], terroryzm['Longitude']],
      popup=terroryzm['Country'],
   ).add_to(m)
```

but its not working.
Location should consist of two numerical values, but 0 - but i dont have empty values
Can you help me?